# Bluetooth speaker not automatically being connected

Tags: windows-8, audio, bluetooth, speakers

After disabling my Toshiba Bluetooth driver and rolling back to the Windows 8 driver (because I couldn't get to the Enhancements tab) I'm having issues with my speaker automatically connecting.

The Bluetooth speaker connects in the Settings App but when going to Playback devices the speaker is listed as disconnected. When you right-click and press `connect`, it works perfectly, though. Is there anything I can do to get it to **connect automatically**? Could I create a batch file or change any setting to get this to work?

[image]